# Trying to get property of non-object in tags.php on line 6

Tags: php, mysql, object, fetch

IT gives an error message which i don't have any idea about. Any Idea how can i fix it ?

Error: Trying to get property of non-object in tags.php on line 6

```
<div class="list-group">
<?php

$result = $database->query("SELECT `name`, `url`, `tag_id` FROM `tags` ORDER BY `tag_id` DESC LIMIT {$settings->sidebar_maximum_tags}");

if($result->num_rows) {

    echo '<h4>' . $language->list->sidebar->tags . '</h4>';

    while($tags = $result->fetch_object()) {

        /* Determine the active author */
        $active = (isset($tag) && $tag->tag_id == $tags->tag_id);

        /* Display tags */
        echo '<a href="tag/' . $tags->url . '" class="list-group-item ' . ($active ? "active" : null) . '">' . $tags->name . '</a>';


    }

}
?>
```

Comment: What does a var_dump() of $result give you? Is it of type object?

Answer (score -1):

result->num_rows

in this num_rows() is a function.

please use braces like this

```
result->num_rows()
```

I hope it will work. Let me know if you get any error again.